# How to pass parameters to the result Function of a createSelector (reselect)

Tags: redux, reselect

My redux store has two independent slices A and B,

I need a memorized selector which returns something derived from B, only if A changes.

For example

```
const getSliceA = (state) => state.A

export const getSliceB = createSelector(
 getSliceA,
 (a) => {  return MyDerive(state.B) }
)
```

My problem is how to send the state or state.B to the resultFunc.

[image]

Comment: So, you want to recalculate only when `state.A` changes AND NOT when `state.B` does. Doesn't a different `state.B` affect the state derivation result? Is there any reason to not provide both state slices to your resultFunc?

Comment: @AndreaCarraro I found a solution with using the "createSelectorCreator" and customizing the "isEqual" of defaultMemoize. As you suggested I had to send both slices to the defaultMemoize. Thx.

Comment: @Hiran can you post your solution as an answer. It would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: @bsapaka Please see my answer if you need any clarification please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const compareBySliceA = (prevSate: RootState, newState: RootState) => {
    // This is just an example you can compare inner of Slice A
    if (newState.SliceA === prevState.SliceB) {
        return true
    }   
    return false;
};

const getDerivedSliceB (state: RootState): List<any> => 
    state.SliceB.filter(ElementB => ElementB.visible) 


const createComparatorSelector = createSelectorCreator(
  defaultMemoize,
  compareBySliceA,
);


 export const myDeepSelector = createComparatorSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state,
  (state: RootState): List<any> => getDerivedSliceB(state),
);
```

Both compareBySliceA and getDerivedSliceB needs the common parent, that is in above example State is the parnet of SliceA and SliceB.